# How can I add a IF EMPTY to PHP Snippet?

Tags: php, wordpress

This snippet works very fine, catch de url parameter and show it in a shortcode, but I want to put a conditional if this parameter is empty: IF "NOMBRE" IS EMPTY, SHOW FOR EXAMPLE THE TEXT "¡HOLA MUNDO!".

```
function custom_shortcode() {
        return '' . htmlspecialchars($_GET["nombre"]) . ''; 
} 
add_shortcode( 'nombre', 'custom_shortcode' );
```

Answer (score 0):

do this

```
if(empty($_GET["nombre"])){
   return "¡HOLA MUNDO!";
}else{
   return '' . htmlspecialchars($_GET["nombre"]) . ''; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but If I put this code, the shortcode is not created and shows literally "Nombre"